# AttributeError: 'WriteConcern' object has no attribute 'acknowledged'

Tags: python, mongodb, gridfs

I have stored a pdf in a MongoDB database and I am accessing it as follows:

```
dbPDFReports = client['pdfReports']
```

where client is my **MongoClient** as follows:

```
client = MongoClient(some_ip, 27017)
```

But I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'WriteConcern' object has no attribute 'acknowledged'
```

Any idea why?

**EDIT**

After upgrading pymongo I got the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bulk import *
  File "/home/inno/InnovAccer/Projects/tiger-global-backend/API/bulk.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pymongo import MongoClient
  File "/home/inno/InnovAccer/Projects/tiger-global-backend/API/pymongo/__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument
  File "/home/inno/InnovAccer/Projects/tiger-global-backend/API/pymongo/collection.py", line 22, in <module>
    from bson.py3compat import (_unicode,
ImportError: cannot import name _unicode
```

Comment: Which pymongo and mongodb versions are you using?

Comment: Mongo version is 3.0.2 and pymongo is 2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem occured due to incompatibility between pymongo and bson which was installed separately. Here's what solved it:

1. Uninstall pymongo and bson
2. Install pymongo only and use pymongo's default generated bson module.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade `pymongo` to the [currently latest (3.0.3) version](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/changelog.html#changes-in-version-3-0-3):

```
pip install --upgrade pymongo
```

Comment: The error went away but I am getting : "ImportError: cannot import name _unicode
"

Comment: @Tarun ok, thanks for trying. Which Python version are you using? Could you also post the complete traceback? Thanks.

Comment: I am using 2.7.6. Added traceback in question

Comment: @Tarun interesting, for starters, try `pip install --upgrade bson`. If it won't help, let's remove pymongo and reinstall it again: `pip uninstall pymongo && pip install --upgrade pymongo`. Thanks.